# Import modules in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following file called `script.js`, where I am making a Wordle-type game:

```js
fetch('https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?length=5&lang=en')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        palabra = response[0].toUpperCase()
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

export function sum(a,b){
  return a+b
}
```

and I want to test it with Jest in a `script.test.js` file:

```js
import { sum } from './script.js'

test('jest setup', ()=>{
    expect(sum(1,3)).toBe(3)
})
```

The test file crashes saying fetch is not defined:

```bash
 FAIL  ./script.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                                                            
    ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

I don't understand why fetch fails with Jest, since it works fine if I run the file. But more importantly, I don't understand why Jest is trying to run fetch, if that is outside the exported function.

Comment: 1. Because it's not running in the environment where you run the file. 2. Because it's inside the imported module.

Comment: Yes, I get that it runs the complete imported module, but don't understand how to import just one function without it failing from other parts of the code. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: You don't. You can't selectively import from the module. If you don't want that fetch to run when the module's imported, move it _into_ a function or _out of_ the module.